# How can I access query in api routes in app directory of next js.As I want to do pagination by querying my requested url

Tags: next.js, pagination, next.js13, next-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjC5k.png)

I am getting squiggly lines below query saying Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Request'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb9pK.png)
This is my blog component

Along with answer, Could someone provide an example of their work where they have accomplished a similar task?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const {searchParams}=new URL(req.url)

}
```

its type is

```
const searchParams: URLSearchParams
```

it has `get` method.

```
 get(name: string): string | null;
```

let's say you have "location" query param

```
const location=searchParams.get("location")
```